# mod-wsgi hangs during posting with https and large data packages

Tags: python, apache, flask, https, mod-wsgi

I created a https environment in win10 with     `apache24` + `openssl(1.1.1)` + `mod-wsgi(4.5.24+ap24vc14)`.

It works well for http posting (no matter how big of the posting data package) but I met a problem for https posting.

For https posting:

1. when the client and the server are the same local machine, also works well no matter how big of the posting data package.
2. when the client is a different machine in the same domain, it also works well for small or medium posting data packages, maybe less than 3M, no precise number.
3. when the client is a different machine in the same domain and posting relatively big data packages, about 5M or 6M, after initial several successful posting, program hangs at server `body=environ['wsgi.input'].read(length)`, no response and no error (seldomly it will pass successfully after a long time, but mostly it willl hang until the connection time out).
4. when debugging the client and the server, the runtime values of `length` are both correct and the same.
5. it seems `body=environ['wsgi.input'].read(length)` comes from `sys.stdin.buffer.read(length)`, but I still can't find the root reason and a solution.

Client code:

```
import json
import requests
import base64
import requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'ALL'
url="https://192.168.0.86"
# url="http://192.168.0.86"
f_img=open("./PICs/20191024142412.jpg",'rb')
# f_img=open("./PICs/20191023092645.jpg",'rb')
json_data={'type':'idpic','image':str(base64.b64encode(f_img.read()),'utf-8')}
result = requests.post(url,json=json_data,verify=False)
result_data=json.loads(result.content)
print(result_data)
```

Part of server codes:

```
class WSGICopyBody(object):

    def __init__(self, application):
        self.application = application

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        from io import StringIO, BytesIO
        length = environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', '0')
        length = 0 if length == '' else int(length)
        body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(length)
        environ['body_copy'] = body
        environ['wsgi.input'] = BytesIO(body)
        app_iter = self.application(environ,self._sr_callback(start_response))
        return app_iter

    def _sr_callback(self, start_response):
        def callback(status, headers, exc_info=None):
            start_response(status, headers, exc_info)
        return callback

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = WSGICopyBody(app.wsgi_app)

@app.route('/',methods=['POST'])
@app.route('/picserver',methods=['POST'])
def picserver():     
    print("before request.get_data")
    request_json_data = request.environ['body_copy']
```